# what is the best way to save the memory and save large numpy array to the h5py file?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, pycharm, h5py

I'm trying to save 50000 with (3,32,32) image file to the h5py file 
but when I stack the modified image to the np.vstack([sal_maps,sal_maps_b]) 
memory is keep going up(pycharm) and after few seconds the memory is full

what is the best way to save this large numpy stack to the h5py file

```
 sal_maps = np.array([], dtype=np.float32).reshape((0,) + img_size)
        probs = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
        preds = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
        for idx, (img, target) in enumerate(dataloader):

    # TODO problem1 idx problem
            sal_maps_b,heat_map_b, probs_b, preds_b = self.generate_image(img, idx)
            sal_maps_b = np.transpose(sal_maps_b, axes=(3,0, 1, 2))

            sal_maps = np.vstack([sal_maps,sal_maps_b])
            probs = np.append(probs, probs_b)
            preds = np.append(preds,preds_b)
            #if idx ==2: break
            if idx % 5 == 0:
                print("idx->{} heat_map->{} sal_maps_size->{}, probs->{} , preds->{}".format(idx,heat_map_b.shape,sal_maps.shape,probs.shape,preds.shape))

        # TODO indent change

                print("result->{}".format(sal_maps.size))
                #f = h5py.File(self.datapath,'w')
                try:
                    #hf = h5py.File(f'./datab/file.hdf5', 'r')
                    print('try.......->{}'.format(sal_maps.shape[0]))
                    with h5py.File(self.datapath, 'a') as hf:
                        print('original saliency shape->{}'.format(hf["saliencys"].shape))

                        hf["saliencys"].resize((hf["saliencys"].shape[0] + sal_maps.shape[0]))
                        hf['saliencys'][-sal_maps.shape[0]:] = sal_maps

                        hf['probs'].resize(hf['probs'].shape[0] + sal_maps.shape[0])
                        hf['probs'][-probs.shape[0]:] = probs

                        hf['preds'].resize(hf['preds'].shape[0] + preds.shape[0])
                        hf['preds'][-preds.shape[0]:] = preds

                        del sal_maps, probs, preds

                        hf.close()

                        sal_maps = np.array([], dtype=np.float32).reshape((0,) + img_size)
                        probs = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
                        preds = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
                        gc.collect()
                    print("done appending....")

                except:
                    print("except......".format(sal_maps.shape))
                    with h5py.File(self.datapath, 'w') as hf:
                        hf.create_dataset('saliencys', data=sal_maps)
                        hf.create_dataset('probs', data=probs)
                        hf.create_dataset('preds', data=preds)
                        hf.close()

                        del sal_maps, probs, preds

                        sal_maps = np.array([], dtype=np.float32).reshape((0,) + img_size)
                        probs = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
                        preds = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
                        gc.collect()

                #with h5py.File(self.datapath, 'w') as hf:
                #    hf.create_dataset('saliencys', data=sal_maps)
                #    hf.create_dataset('probs', data=probs)
                #    hf.create_dataset('preds', data=preds)
                #    hf.close()
                sal_maps = np.array([], dtype=np.float32).reshape((0,) + img_size)
                probs = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
                preds = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
                print('Save_saliency_maps::',idx)
                if idx >= 0 and idx <3000:continue
                else: break
```

this is my example but I got an error with

> raise TypeError("Only chunked datasets can be resized") TypeError:
>   Only chunked datasets can be resized

Comment: Don't use `np.vstack` or `np.append` to create arrays iteratively.  List append is much faster, (and memory friendly) than repeated array concatenation.  Use just one `vstack` to join a whole list of arrays.  That said, you may still have memory problems, if the total array size is too big.

Comment: To have to define the datasets for growth at the start., with appropriate max shape(s), and chunking.  https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#resizable-datasets

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, minimize calls to `dataset.resize()`. There is overhead with it. To demonstrate, I created a small program to measure the speed when adding 50,000 arrays of (3,32,32) to a single dataset. Two methods are used:

1. Create a fixed size dataset with size (50000,3,32,32).
2. Create a resizable dataset with initial size (0,3,32,32), and
   resize before every image write.

Summary of performance for each (writing to a HDD, likely writing to a SSD would be faster):

1. Elapsed time = 8.7 sec
2. Elapsed time = 91.0 sec

Note: times above are for adding or resizing data on `axis=0`. Performance is substantially slower if you modify to add or resize data on `axis=3`. In other words, performance of both methods depends on the axis.

In the ideal situation, you can predict the dataset size in advance, then size appropriately when you create it (e.g., you know the number of images). In many situations you will have to estimate the initial size, then check the dataset before adding data. Use resize() to add rows when the dataset is full.

Code for performance comparison below. `i_cnt` used to adjust the number of images for testing.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import time

sal_maps_b = np.arange(3.*32.*32.).reshape(3,32,32)
i_cnt=50000

start = time.clock()
with h5py.File('SO_59356936_add.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    sals = h5f.create_dataset('saliencys', (i_cnt,3,32,32))
    for i in range(i_cnt):
        if i%(i_cnt/10)==0:
            print('adding saliency data-> {}, {}%'.format(i, i/i_cnt*100) )
        sals[i, :,:,:] = (i+1)*sal_maps_b[:]

print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) )    
print ('Done #1')

start = time.clock()
with h5py.File('SO_59356936_resize.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    sals = h5f.create_dataset('saliencys', (0,3,32,32), maxshape=(None, 3,32,32))
    for i in range(i_cnt):
        if i%(i_cnt/10)==0:
            print('resize/add saliency data-> {}, {}%'.format(i, i/i_cnt*100) )
        sals.resize (i_cnt, axis=0)
        sals[i, :,:,:] = (i+1)*sal_maps_b[:]

print ('Elapsed time =', (time.clock() - start) )    
print ('Done #2')
```